# How fgets reads line after line from a file?

Tags: c, fgets

Let say I have:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 256

void copy(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
     char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
     while (fgets(buffer, CHUNK_SIZE, input) != NULL) {
          fputs(buffer, output);
     }
}
```

But in the while loop, `fgets` gets the same parameters - so how does it know to read the next line from the file in each iteration of `while`? Doesn't it suppose to get stuck in infinite loop because it always reads the same line?

Comment: Files are accessed sequentially. See `fseek()` and `ftell()`.

Comment: For the same reason that `fscanf` "knows" that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: added extra explanation as @KlasLindbäck pointed out that my answer wasn't entirely correct

The File is a struct that contains a field "fd" which is an integer that identifies the OS file descriptor of this file, this file descriptor can be used to retrieve the current location in the file you're reading. If you want more information about the File struct [here](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-file-structure-and-file-pointer/) and file descriptor [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

TL;DR: The FILE struct somehow stores where it's reading.

Comment: There is no field in the FILE struct that holds the current position in the file. When you call `ftell`, the current position is obtained by calling `lseek` on the underlying file descriptor and then modifying by the number of unread bytes in the `FILE` buffer.

Comment: Thank you for telling me , i edited my answer to be correct -hopefully-

Answer (score 0):

An open file internally keeps track of the current position for the next read operation. Whenever you read from the file the position is updated.
You can get the current postition with `ftell()` and set the current position with `fseek()`.